# How to correctly set ASPNETCORE_ENV to non-development value?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy a web application to an Azure App Service. I am testing with just the default application that is generated when you create a new web application in Visual Studio 2017 choosing React + Redux as the app skeleton. Here is the error I get:

[image: picture of the error]

`Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.`

Some googling sends me here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/06/21/asp-net-core-with-entity-framework-core-aspnetcore_environment/

So I changed my project properties:

[image]

I picked `Production`, but I suppose anything besides `Development` would suffice. It didn't work, so I make sure my publish settings are set to deploy as Release:

[image]

And solution config:

[image]

Still, the same error comes up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to restart the application again and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I ended up publishing to a new web application and that worked, didn't notice any configuration differences but I did try restarting to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

See my web app settings below, hope it will help you.
1. AppSettings.json

```
"Data": {
"ConnectionString": "Server=****.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=***;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=pankajrawatqa;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

},

2. Azure Web App Settings
   [image: Application Settings]

Comment: I had matching values for everything relevant. Thanks for the attempt though.